# Disable horizontal AutScroll in Winforms, not just scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, autoscroll

I've been fighting a winform panel autoscroll property for past hour and cant get it to work. 
What i want is to have a vertical scroll but not a horizonatal.
I was able to hide the vertical scrollbar, but scroll is still possible by clicking on components close to edge or by mouse wheel.

Before clicking on checkbox:

[image]

After:

[image]

I want to completly disable horizontal autoscroll...

Panel is Anchored: top,left,right,bot
Code for setting the autoscroll:

```
 PANEL.AutoScroll = false;
 PANEL.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
 PANEL.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
 PANEL.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
 PANEL.AutoScroll = true;
```

THANKS FOR ANY HELP

Comment: Use a FlowLayoutPanel instead.

Comment: Changing the HorizontalScroll properties has no effect whatsoever when you set AutoScroll to true.  That checkbox that displays "CM" seems to be quite a bit wider than necessary.

Comment: Or put this Panel inside another Panel and AutoScroll the container Panel. If you increase just the height of the child Panel...

Answer (score -1):

Try to dock your panel first to the form.